# Why does node.js http doesn't call the end event when there is no data listener?

Tags: node.js, http

I am sending data from a file to a server as a HTTP POST request like that:

```
var options = {
    "hostname": "example.com",
    "port": 42,
    "path": "/whatever",
    "method": "PUT",
    "headers" : {
        // a few headers
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on("end", function () {
        console.log("The request is finished");
    });
});

var stream = fs.createReadStream("/tmp/someFile");

stream.on("data", function(data) {
    req.write(data);
});

stream.on("end", function() {
    req.end();
});
```

I am listening for `res.on("end")` in order to do more stuff after the file is uploaded.

However, in the example above, the `res.on("end")` is never called.

What is striking, is that when I add a listener for the `data` event, `res.on("end")` is called reliably.

This even works if I completely ignore the data as in the example below:

```
var options = {
    "hostname": "example.com",
    "port": 42,
    "path": "/whatever",
    "method": "PUT",
    "headers" : {
        // a few headers
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on("data", function () {
        /*
         * I don't even care for the data returned...
         */
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
        console.log("The request is finished");
    });
});

var stream = fs.createReadStream("/tmp/someFile");

stream.on("data", function(data) {
    req.write(data);
});

stream.on("end", function() {
    req.end();
});
```

Is this a bug? Is it the expected behaviour? Am I doing something wrong creating the request or reading the data from file?

Comment: It's expected behavior for [readable streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) with [Node 0.10 and later](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/21/streams2/). The stream will begin paused unless a `'data'` or `'readable'` event is bound, or it's told explicitly to `.resume()`. Inversely, you only need to wait for `'end'` if you care about the `'data'`. You can skip both otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is the expected behavior.**

http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end

> **Event: 'end'**
>
> This event fires when no more data will be provided.
>
> Note that the end event will not fire unless the data is completely consumed. This can be done by switching into flowing mode, or by calling read() repeatedly until you get to the end.

**From the doc :**

- http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

  > The optional callback parameter will be added as a one time listener for the 'response' event.
- *'response' event* http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_response

  > The response argument will be an instance of http.IncomingMessage.
- *http.IncomingMessage* http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage

  > It implements the Readable Stream interface.
- *Readable Stream 'end' event* http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end